# use hasClass and addClass

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I use jquery draggable and touchend when I use ipad.

```js
$('.draggable').on("touchend", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($(".year").hasClass("year2")) {
    $(".year2").addClass("drop")
  } else if ($(".year").hasClass("year58")) {
    $(".year58").addClass("drop")
  } else {
    return false;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="draggable">
  <img src="img/draggable.png" alt="draggable">
  <div class="drag-area">
    <div class="year year1"></div>
    <div class="year year2"></div>
    <div class="year year3"></div>
    <div class="year year4"></div>
    <div class="year year5"></div>
    <div class="year year58"></div>
    <div class="btn draggable-ball">
      <img src="img/draggable-ball.png" alt="draggable-ball">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to use JS and if else statement to add the class in the div where I want to add,
and I write like this but it doesn't work,how can i do?

Comment: can you provide css and explain what you are trying to accomplish/what you think your logic should be doing?

Comment: I want to use if else statement to add the class and the bottom have a button to click to make a distinction and have different popup to show

Comment: You want it to highlight if it is dragged onto that element? Trying to figure out what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: `if ($(".year").hasClass("year2"))` - `hasClass` returns true, if _any_ of the selected elements have the class. And `$(".year")` has selected _all_ your year elements to begin with. So this condition is true, and with `$(".year2").addClass("drop")` you are then adding that class to _all_ year elements. What you _actually_ want here, I still can't tell either though.

Comment: It might make more sense if the `drag-area` wasn't *inside* the `draggable` and you wanted to highlight which div was being dragged over.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to determine what element it gets the event. You want to use the target.

```js
$('.draggable').on("mouseup touchend", (e) => {
  const elem = $(e.target);
  e.preventDefault();
  if (elem.is(".year2, .year58")) {
   elem.addClass('dropped');
  }
})
```

```css
.dropped {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="draggable">
  <img src="img/draggable.png" alt="draggable">
  <div class="drag-area">
    <div class="year year1">1</div>
    <div class="year year2">2</div>
    <div class="year year3">3</div>
    <div class="year year4">4</div>
    <div class="year year5">5</div>
    <div class="year year58">6</div>
    <div class="btn draggable-ball">
      <img src="img/draggable-ball.png" alt="draggable-ball">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```